# Oracle Cube Replica in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cube, olap-cube

Oracle has a cube function for groupby clause which takes 2 or more columns and groups the results set in all possible combinations of columns passed to the cube function.

```
SELECT Time, Region, Department, 
   sum(Profit) AS Profit FROM sales
   GROUP BY CUBE  (Time, Region, Dept)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a68003/rollup_c.htm#32311

Is there a similar function in python pandas or any other python framework which takes in list of pandas columns and produce a new data frame which has results of all possible group by.

I am coding my own version of cube in python. Good to know if already exists one.

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas you should automatize a function that concatenates horizontally the results of the following groupby

```
pd.concat([
     df.groupby("Time")['Profit].sum().reset_index(),
     df.groupby("Profit")['Profit].sum().reset_index(),
     df.groupby("Region")['Profit].sum().reset_index(),
     df.groupby(["Time", "Region"])['Profit].sum().reset_index(),
     df.groupby(["Time", "Dept"])['Profit].sum().reset_index(),
     df.groupby(["Region", "Dept"])['Profit].sum().reset_index(),
     df.groupby(["Time", "Region", "Dept"])['Profit].sum().reset_index(),
    ],
    axis=0
)
```

To do this I suggest using `itertools.combinations`